# In which scenarios asp:DropDownList will remain its selected value when returning to form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have several asp:dropdownlists on my search form. After selecting items from them and clicking search button I will get a list of results under the search form. The list contains items, on which I can click and the the searchform will be replaced with detailed view of that item. Above the forms container (place where I can navigate between search and detailed view) there are header-like navigation menu, where are usual menu items (search,add new item,etc).

Imagine following scenario: I fill dropdowns  and other search fields with info and press the search button. I get the results list. I open one item from list to see the detailed view. I press the Search button on the header-like navigation menu to go back to my search results. All the results will remain the same i had before i left the results list and all the search parameter fields has the same values and ddl has same selected values i entered when i made the search.   - It would be perfect scenario. BUT, instead this, ONE of the dropdowns decided not to show the same value which i used for searching. Its showing the default value, which will be there when i haven't use search yet.

Does anyone can explain different scenarios, when doesnt the dropdown  remain its selected item, and when it does?

Comment: How you binding data to those dropdowns? Show code.

Comment: No actual databinding - list will be generated in ascx file. And also ListItems are added there.

Answer (score 0):

The most common scenario where the drop down list will not retain its selected item is when the contents of the drop down list are rebound and no matching value exists in the new set of data with the previous set of data, for example:

On initial page load you have a drop down list with `A`, `B` and `C` in the drop down list. The user selects `B` from the drop down list.

Now the user performs an action on the page (i.e. clicks search button) and the page posts back to the server. The result of the search populates the drop down list with `D` ,`E` and `F`; obviously none of these match the value of `B` selected earlier, so the drop down list selects the first item in the drop down list, which is the value `D` at this point.

It is a common misconception that `ViewState` is required to maintain the selected item value, but it is not necessary to achieve that effect, it just generally makes it easier. So turning off `ViewState` does not absolutely mean you cannot keep track of the selected item between post backs.

Read [TRULY UNDERSTANDING VIEWSTATE](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) for more information on how to use and not use `ViewState` effectively in your application.

Comment: It that case, does the value reselecting uses ddl item's value or the id? Actually, its getting weirder - I have 9 values in that ddl and only the last one does not get reselected...